# Salesforce Classic Notes and Attachment in Lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, salesforce-classic

We have Notes and Attachment related list on Account, we can see list of attachments in Classic however same user if he logs in to lightning experience cannot view Notes and Attachments records in the related list. We have tried to pull the files related list as well, but cannot view the records. Could you please let us know how can we view the attachments records in lightning ?

Thanks
Chaithra

Comment: Are those attachments directly related to Accounts or related to Account's Contacts and Opportunities? Unfortunately lightning does not rollsup the related attachment unlike in classic. here is article mentioned that feature- [Cannot see files and attachments related to Opportunities and Contacts on Account records in Lightning](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231874&type=1)

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert notes and attachments to lightning files

https://www.eternussolutions.com/2017/11/14/convert-attachments-files-9-easy-steps/